# Use infinite loop to restart program on any key press and to leave loop on specific key press

Tags: c#

I currently have user entering a value for temperature and am giving recommendation based on temperature. I would like to setup a loop to ask the user for input until the user presses either "N" or "n".

For example:

//user input

//temp recommendation

//Continue? Press any key, N or n to exit.

Any key pressed would again ask for user input and N or n would result in program thanking user on screen no longer showing temp recommendation. Professor suggested we use additional method to achieve expected result.

Current incorrect code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Continue? Press any key to continue, N or n to exit:\n");
{
if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.N)
else if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.n)
return;}
}
Console.WriteLine("Thank you");
```

Comment: In what way is in incorrect? Does it throw an error or not function as expected?

Comment: The else if line has an issue. "ConsoleKey does not contain a definition for n"

Comment: Next time please put it in the question - we're not mind readers. I looked up ConsoleKey and its true - there is no definition for n: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekey(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a local variable in a while loop as follows:

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
    bool keepGoing = true;

    while (keepGoing)
    {
        DoYourWork();

        Console.WriteLine("Continue? Press any key to continue, N or n to exit:");

        var userWantsToContinue = Console.ReadLine();

        keepGoing = userWantsToContinue?.ToUpper() != "N";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter the `do..while` loop :)

```
private static void DoWhatever(string data)
{
    // process your temp
}

// inside main somewhere
Console.WriteLine("Enter temp:");

do
{
    var temp = Console.ReadLine();
    DoWhatever(temp);
    Console.WriteLine("Continue? Press any key to continue, N or n to exit:\n");
}while(Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.N);
Console.WriteLine("Thank you");
```

Comment: @mjwills thanks for that, my bad; i took what the OP had for granted.
Updated the answer (it is actually even neater now as we lost 2 lines of code)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *break* to exit from loop

```
while(true)
{
  //process temperature conversion
  Console.Write("Continue? Press any key to continue, N or n to exit:");
  if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.N)
  {
    break;
  }

}
```